# How to create an iframe inside a google addon

Tags: google-apps-script, gmail, gmail-addons

I am trying to create a sample addon which have an iframe.
I am getting the following error:

> **The value returned from Apps Script has a type that cannot be used by the add-ons platform. Also make sure to call build on any builder before returning it.**

Comment: Are you referring to gmail addon ?

Comment: Yes @HariBalaji

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't use iframes with the Gmail add-on. You can only build cards using google apps scripts. Here are some more restrictions https://developers.google.com/gmail/add-ons/guides/restrictions

Comment: So is there any other alternative way to make a another website enable in my addon?

Comment: You would need to create an extension instead of an add-on. Gmail Add-Ons are still very new (Launched in October) so this might be something they add eventually.

Comment: Yes that is correct. Though add-ons are at nascent state, we can request the devs for new features at https://issuetracker.google.com/issues?q=componentid:325133%20

Comment: @MichaelMelo There is *IFRAME Sandbox Mode* in https://developers.google.com/apps-script/migration/iframe, can this be used in gmail-add-on please ?

Answer (score 1):

**In short : NO**

Add-ons are built using *Cards*. These *Cards* in turn render markup. Which implies that you can't use any form of HTML inside these cards. You would have to call the methods provided by google to render UI. You can however create a button to open a URL in a new window. Check [this](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/card-service/button#setOpenLink(OpenLink)).